# Java: KeyListener class is not detecting key presses, only key releases

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm building a very simple game to practice my rudimentary Java knowledge, and my `KeyManager` class wasn't responding.

```
package me.holdenew.game.keyinputs;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;

    public KeyManager() {

        keys = new boolean[256];
    }

    public void update() {

        up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_W] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP];
        down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN];
        left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
        right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(e.getKeyCode()) + " pressed");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(e.getKeyCode()) + " released");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

I added `print` statements, which are getting called when I press keys, so I know that the class is set up correctly. But, if I press multiple keys at once or hold one down and press things, then *all* of the keys are unresponsive and only the `keyReleased` print statement is being called, not the `keyPressed` one. Can I please have some help resolving this problem?

Comment: This is probably a hardware limitation of your keyboard (and most keyboards).  See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses and https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108996/how-to-avoid-ghosting-when-pressing-multiple-keys.